# Hide "<li>" element if there is no data-category related to data-filter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Please see this picture first:

[image]

I have added the video in a div but if I remove this div then `<li data-filter="4" id="videos">Videos</li>` should get hidden and if I add a video then `<li data-filter="4" id="videos">Videos</li>` should be visible.

How is that possible with JavaScript or jQuery?

```html
<ul class="simplefilter">
  <li class="active" data-filter="all">All</li>
  <li data-filter="1">Light decoration</li>
  <li data-filter="2">Water supply</li>
  <li data-filter="3">Mobile repairing</li>
  <li data-filter="4" id="videos">Videos</li>
</ul>

<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filtr-item" data-category="4">
  <div class="hover ehover14">
    <a href="gallary/1.mp4" class="swipebox" title="Branded accessories.">
      <video controls class="img-responsive img-size">
        <source src="gallary/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
      </video>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your goal you can loop through each `data-filter` element and check for matching elements with the same value in their `data-category`. If there are none, hide the original element. Try this:

```js
$('li[data-filter]:not(.all)').each((i, el) => {
  let hasVideos = $(`div[data-category="${el.dataset.filter}"]`).length != 0;
  $(el).toggle(hasVideos);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="simplefilter">
  <li class="all active" data-filter="all">All</li>
  <li data-filter="1">Light decoration</li>
  <li data-filter="2">Water supply</li>
  <li data-filter="3">Mobile repairing</li>
  <li data-filter="4" id="videos">Videos</li>
</ul>

<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filtr-item" data-category="4">
  <div class="hover ehover14">
    <a href="gallary/1.mp4" class="swipebox" title="Branded accessories.">
      <video controls class="img-responsive img-size">
        <source src="gallary/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
      </video>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You it worked but it is also affecting the "All" section how to exclude "All" section?

Comment: You can put a class on that item and use `:not()` to exclude it. I updated the example in the answer to show this

Answer (score 1):

> you can check file url if file exist then display otherwise hide this block

```
$.ajax({
url:'http://www.your-file-url',
type:'HEAD',
error: function()
{
    //file not exists
},
success: function()
{
    //file exists
}
```

});`enter code here`